# Choosing a custom proposal distribution in Metropolis-Hastings Monte Carlo

Tags: monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

I have many states and have calculated a good custom proposal distribution for my Monte Carlo simulation. The system reaches a good solution faster than if it were to just use a randomly selected proposed switch state. Is there some way to ensure detailed balance no matter my proposal distribution (which is not continuous)?

$$\pi _{i}P_{ij}=\pi _{j}P_{ji}$$

I assume I would need to pick some acceptance ratio based on this distribution, but it is unclear to me as to how to do this?

Comment: M-H ensures detailed balance regardless of the proposal distribution. You might be thinking about the Metropolis algorithm?

Comment: @KevinLi ah perhaps, I am looking at a statistical mechanics book. So physically we take the relative probility of being in a state as the Boltzman factor e^(E/kT), so the probabilities would remain the same even with this new method? And so the acceptance probability would just be e^(Delta E /kT)*g(x')/g(x) ?